# Как собрать готовый .appx файл на Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows, unity3d, windows-10, microsoft-store

У меня есть готовые исходники игры Unity и нажал я на Build. Потом оно собрало какой-то проект, который можно открыть в Visual Studio. Как теперь собрать уже готовый файл игры для Windows store? Дает ошибку (на скриншоте). [image: Написано что какой то .dll файл не найдено]

Comment: не ошибку, а ошибкИ. И из скрина не понятно их конкретное описание, которое было бы неплохо в вопрос скинуть как цитату...... а из скрина понятно лишь, что  что-то не найдено..

Comment: Попробуйте перебилдить под разные фреймворки

Comment: Уточните, что именно вы сделали для появления ошибок. И при использовании скриншотов нужно их делать более информативными. В вашем случае это скриншот, где показано, что да, из-за чего-то действительно вышла ошибка. Но ясно ни причин, ни связей. Открытые окна также не показывают ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать непосредственно на вопрос "Как собрать готовый .appx файл".
Правой клавишей на проекте, магазин, создать пакет приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда программа предложит пройти проверки и тесты - лучше не отказывайтесь, если вы планируете публиковать свое приложение.